# Django Form text input field not showing in browser

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Django model and form for a comment submission form i want under my blog post. The form however, does not show in my browser and i assume isn't loaded. I'm new to coding and have been looking for a solution for a long time to no avail.

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.text
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Comment
from django.db import models

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ['post' 'author']
        fields = ['text']
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.views import generic
from .forms import CommentForm
from .models import Comment, Post


def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('/blog/<int:pk>', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {"form":form, "post": post})
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
                path('', ListView.as_view(
                    queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],
                    template_name="blog/blog.html")),
                re_path("(?P<pk>\d+)", DetailView.as_view(model = Post,
                    template_name = "blog/post.html")),
                re_path('blog/<int:pk>', views.add_comment_to_post, name='post_comment'),
]
```

post.html

```html
<div class="container">
    <h5>New comment</h5>

    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'post_comment' post.pk %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Post Comment</button>
    </form>

    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        <div class="card" style="margin: 20px 0px 20px 5px">
            <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
            <strong>{{ comment.author|capfirst }}</strong>
            <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No comments yet. Be the the first to reply</p>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

I can sumbit comments through the admin panel so i believe the actual model is working as intended. I think the problem is most likely in my urls.py since the model is working and this is the file i currently understand the least.

sorry for posting so much code too but i'm too new to coding to narrow it down further for you kind people.

Comment: Reading from your view, you don't hit a `return` when reaching the page from a POST request with an invalid form. Could it be that? I mean, can you test by moving the last line of your view out of the `else` block?

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly say what fields you want in the form. You can read more details in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ['post', 'author']
        fields = ['text', ....]
```

**views.py**

```py
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('/blog/<int:pk>', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {"form":form, "post": post})
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25], template_name="blog/blog.html")),
    re_path("(?P<pk>\d+)", DetailView.as_view(model=Post, template_name="blog/post.html")),
    # you were using re_path here instead of path
    path('blog/<int:pk>', views.add_comment_to_post, name='post_comment'),
]
```

**post.html**

```html
<div class="container">
    <h5>New comment</h5>

    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'post_comment' post.pk %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Post Comment</button>
    </form>

    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        <div class="card" style="margin: 20px 0px 20px 5px">
            <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
            <strong>{{ comment.author|capfirst }}</strong>
            <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No comments yet. Be the the first to reply</p>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Also, you don't need to call the CommentForm in your form since you're importing it in your views.py. Another thing is that the last line of your `views.py` will never be executed since you have return inside your if/else conditions. Nevertheless, you definitely don't need that.

Comment: thanks for the corrections! unfortunately however, this didn't solve the problem

Comment: I've edited my answer with some other things I think it was missing, especially you forgot to pass the post.id on your form action.

Comment: I made these changes and got a "Reverse for 'post_comment' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/blog/<int:pk>']" when loading the page. Also you wrote the html with the title template.html instead of post.html. Do i need two seperate .html files to add a comment section? I only have one atm

Comment: I named as `template.html` because it's generic but I don't think you should have two separate templates. Can you update your question with the changes you've made so it's easy to follow

Comment: edited the post. " action="{% url 'post_comment' post.pk %}" " is what is producing an error now i believe

Comment: I've edited my answer again and made a comment. If that doesn't work, I'm running out of options. I believe your last issue is with your URLs and that's what I just updated

Comment: This fixed the page loading problem but the form it self still isn't showing in browser. Thank you for your contribution, i did learn from your suggestions. unfortunately i seemingly write some very unfixable code haha

Comment: Thanks. Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/). You can do just `{{ form }}` on your template but `{{ form.as_p }}` should work